# Stop multiple animation function on complete and reset

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I've got the following animation...

```
$('.animate_camper').click(function(){
   startCamper();
   setTimeout("leaveScreen()",1000) ;
});

var num = 1;

function startCamper(){
  num++;
  $(".bus").animate({top:"-=6px"},150).animate({top:"+=6px"},150);
  if(num<4){
         setTimeout("startCamper()",300);
  } else {
     setTimeout("bounceCamper()",300);
  }
}

function bounceCamper(){
  $(".bus").animate({top:"-=6px"},150).animate({top:"+=6px"},150);
  setTimeout("bounceCamper()",300);
}

function leaveScreen(){
  $(".camper").animate({left:"140%"}, 3000).fadeTo(400, 0)
}
```

So as you can see on link click the campervan starts bouncing up and down on a loop, it then drives off to the right and fades out.

However although it fades out the element is still there (although hidden) bouncing up and down.

I need it to fade out, then stop bouncing and reset back to its orginal position so that it can run again if the link is clicked again.

ANY HELP IS VERY MUCH APPRECIATED!!

Comment: have you tried `stop()` ??

Answer (score 0):

<s>You want a "stop", jQuery has a function named [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).</s>

> **.stop**( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )
>
> Returns: jQuery
>
> Description: Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

Your bouncing is caused by this piece of code which calls itself after 300ms:

```
function bounceCamper(){
  $(".bus").animate({top:"-=6px"},150).animate({top:"+=6px"},150);
  setTimeout("bounceCamper()",300);
}
```

You need to break that timer either by referencing the timer via a variable and use `clearTimeout`:

```
var timer;

function bounceCamper(){
  $(".bus").animate({top:"-=6px"},150).animate({top:"+=6px"},150);
  timer = setTimeout("bounceCamper()",300);
}

//stop the existing timer to break loop
clearTimeout(timer);
```

or conditionally break the call using a boolean flag:

```
var toLoop = true;

function bounceCamper(){
  $(".bus").animate({top:"-=6px"},150).animate({top:"+=6px"},150);
  if(toLoop) setTimeout("bounceCamper()",300);
}

//stop the existing timer by setting the flag to false
toLoop = false;
```

As for resetting, you need to set back the position of your element after the `fadeOut`. You can do that by using `.css()`.

Comment: can you tell me where i need to put this? I have tried adding a stop function after the fadeto, but it doesn't stop the hidden element bouncing or reset its position.

Comment: @bipen Yes I have tried adding .stop, but it doesn't seem to work! I've tried it in several places with no joy, I only want to stop the bouncing and reset after it travels left and fades out. Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: it would go before animate like so `$(".bus").stop().animate(`

Comment: @Joseph the Dreamer You are definately on the right track! But i'm still struggling. I couldn't get the first method to work, and the second method stops it bouncing before it drives off to the right.

Here is a link to the project i'm working on (hope it helps)...
www.luketom.com/clients/gastro3/

Click the enter screen to move onto slide 2, then click any link on the signpost to activate the animation. If you inspect the camper element you will see it is hidden but bouncing. Thanks again for all your help so far!!!